# Undo baseline IBM Rational Team Concert

Tags: ibm-rational

I accidentally created a baseline for a component in my RTC stream and also delivered it. I was wondering if there is anyway to delete the baseline or undo the baseline. If anyone could please help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't delete the baseline but you can rename it to indicate your mistake e.g. don't use.
2. You can go to your stream an replace the component with the previous baseline. (note: anyone else that's already accepted it will then see it as an outgoing change and may delivery it again).
3. You can create a reverse patch and deliver that to undo the changes the erroneous baseline delivered.

Comment: How do I rename a baseline